# Get indexes of multiple pandas columns by names

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, dataframe

I want to get the numerical indexes of a selection of pandas dataframe columns.

With one column it's very simple:

```
nonzero(df.columns.values == 'conditionA')
```

but with multiple elements?
I have something that works but is verbose and hugly:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['conditionF', 'conditionB', 'conditionA', 'conditionD', 'conditionC'])

cols_to_find = ['conditionA', 'conditionB', 'conditionC']
[i for i in range(len(df.columns.values)) if df.columns.tolist()[i] in cols_to_find ]
```

Better ideas?

Comment: try `np.nonzero(df.columns.isin(to_find))`

Comment: That's the answer! It was just there... I was looking for a isin() function and did not go for a method!
Tx!

Comment: @behzad.nouri please post it as the answer so Gioelelm would be able to accept it and show the others that the issue is clearly solved

Comment: @behzad.nouri: nice, but it doesn't keep the order from the list of column names, it rearranges them in increasing order.

Comment: I posted a solution that preserves order.

Comment: Gioelelm, I posted a working solution two years ago. You are able to click accept on answers.

Answer (score 13):

This works, and also **preserves order**:

```
[df.columns.get_loc(col) for col in cols_to_find]
[2, 1, 4]
```

List comprehensions are your friend.

(Note: this solution had gotten one comment from someone who confused that in pandas, (row-)index can have duplicates, but column names are typically unique).

Answer (score -1):

```
df=pd.DataFrame(columns=['conditionF', 'conditionB', 'conditionA', 'conditionD', 'conditionC'])
def search():
    search=['conditionA', 'conditionB', 'conditionC']
    c=len(search)
    for i in df.columns.values:
        print(i)
        if i in search:
            c-=1
    return c==0
search()
```