# Get column-index from column-name in pandas?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, indices

Get column-index of a specific column-name e.g. `Address` should return 2 (you can assume the column exists and is unique). (Yes I know you shouldn't need to do this in general, this is only for debug while coding)

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(3,5), columns = ['Name','Age','Address','City','Zip'])
```

Related questions:

- this is the inverse of [**Retrieve name of column from its Index in Pandas**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43068412/retrieve-name-of-column-from-its-index-in-pandas)
  , but harder
- and a simpler version of [**Get indexes of multiple pandas columns by names**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22934609/get-indexes-of-multiple-pandas-columns-by-names), where returning cols in the right order is tricky
- also not looking for case-insensitive or regex matches on colname, although if you want to show that, you can
- the search ["pandas get column index from name"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=pandas+get+column+index+from+name) gives a very jumbled bag of 198 results.
- someday we will make all the above jumble canonical. (Then again, someday we'll colonize Mars)
- oh dear, I just found out the following previous asking, which could not be found by keyword search, probably because they said 'retrieving' [**Retrieving column index from column name in python pandas**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13021654/retrieving-column-index-from-column-name-in-python-pandas)